# Dummy questions about setting up git on amazon cloud ec2

Tags: linux, eclipse, git, amazon-ec2

first of all, apologize for dummy questions that I might throw here. It would be nice if you could point the directions where should I go from here.

I'm totally new to version control(as well as git) and cloud system. However, it came to the point that I have to develop php web based application on AWS EC2 instance and make codes contributable for future developers.

I did successfully create EC2 instance that run PHP/MySQL and map the domain with Elastic IP. So the website is now publicly accessible via port 80.

I also installed git using `$sudo yum install git` and configed user.name and user.email

I then, go to root folder of the website (e.g. public_html) and run ‘`git init`’ which create the fold “.git” and I then add file using “`git add .`” and commit “`git commit -m ‘initial upload’`”

Is that the right way to go? Would it be ok to have the project folder sitting on /public_html (where accessible from anyone).

If above is ok, then where should I go from here?
I would like to have git server running on EC2 that allow developers to connect from their local machines (e.g. Eclipse) while being able to keep the backup and compare the different between codes.

What detail do I suppose to give developers so that they can connect to git server and working on project?

I quick direction or few keywords to do more research would help.

Answer (score 11):

look [here](http://shirtdev.wordpress.com/2011/05/04/setting-up-a-git-repository-on-an-amazon-ec2-instance/) for more information on setting up git on amazon ec2

to allow developers to use you git, you just need to give them the git server url.

Direct quote from the site i'm linking to.

> "First and foremost, you need to add your EC2 identity to the ssh
>   authentication agent.  This prevents problems with git later, namely
>   getting the error “Permission denied (publickey).” when trying to do a
>   git push to the EC2 repository.
>
> ```
> ssh-add path/to/privateEC2key.pem
> ```
>
> Now you can go ahead and create the git repository on the EC2
>   instance.
>
> ```
> ssh username@hostname.com 
> mkdir the_project.git 
> cd the_project.git 
> git init --bare
> ```
>
> So not much going on here, all we do is create an empty repository and
>   then leave. Now, on the local machine, you do something like the
>   following:
>
> ```
> cd the_project 
> git init
> git add . 
> git commit -m "Initial git commit message" 
> git remote add origin username@hostname.com:the_project.git 
> git config --global remote.origin.receivepack "git receive-pack" 
> git push origin master
> ```
>
> The ‘git config’ command is a fix that I found necessary to be able to
>   push to the EC2 repository."

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, AlekCarlsen. I did follow the instruction and have a better understanding git and the way it works now.

My solution now is to host the main repo on GitHub and clone it to development environments when require (as developers). Once the change made and ready to go, I'll pull all the change to live from GitHub. :)

Answer (score 3):

The mentioned link by Alex gives a good starting point to setup git on ec2. But I followed a little different approach as mentioned here. [link](http://devoncmather.com/setting-aws-ec2-instance-lamp-git/#launchInstance). Direct Quotes from the page:

"Connecting with SSH without a PEM key" : So either you add the ec2 private key and add it as a entity in your ssh authentication agent or create a new ssh key for your user and use that. Steps to be followed are:

**Create SSH Key**

First up you will need to navigate to your .ssh folder on your local machine :

```
cd
cd .ssh
```

if this folder doesn’t exist use mkdir to make it.

Once in your ssh folder on your local machine which should be in /Users/yourusername/.ssh generate your key by executing the following.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 1024
```

When prompted enter the file name to save the key enter id_rsa_aws, when prompted to enter a password leave blank.

In your .ssh directory execute the following command and copy the output to paste later.

```
cat id_rsa_aws.pub
```

Now connect to you AWS instance using you PEM key

```
ssh -i path/to/yourkeyname.pem ubuntu@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Once in

```
echo 'the key you copied from id_rsa_aws.pub' >> .ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 640 .ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 750 .ssh
```

Now you go to your machine and type

```
cd desired directory
git clone ubuntu@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:<path_to_your_just_created_git_server>
```

If you did all the above mentioned steps correct, the only warning you might get is

```
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
```

That's ok. Now you can copy all your code into the clone directory, and follow the following steps:

```
git add . 
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push origin master // If working on master branch
```

Answer (score 0):

i created a GitHub gist with all the details hope it helps 
https://gist.github.com/eslam-mahmoud/35777e4382599438023abefc9786a382

```
//add your EC2 .pem file to ssh kys
ssh-add ~/aws/mypemfile.pem 

//create bare repo on AWS EC2 webserver and deploy on demand
mkdir ~/git/the_project 
cd ~/git/the_project
git init --bare

//create local repo and track remote one
cd ~/git/the_project 
git init
git add . 
git commit -m "Initial git commit message" 
git remote add aws ubuntu@1.1.1.1:~/git/the_project 
git config --global remote.origin.receivepack "git receive-pack" 
git push aws master
//create tag
git tag -a v0.1 -m "my version 0.1"
//push tags
git push aws --tags

//Or you have one so you push your updates 
git remote add aws ubuntu@1.1.1.1:~/git/the_project 
git config --global remote.origin.receivepack "git receive-pack" 
git push aws master
//create tag
git tag -a v0.1 -m "my version 0.1"
//push tags
git push aws --tags

//on server create another local repo that track the bare one to deploy
git clone ~/git/the_project
cd ./the_project
//checkout tag
git checkout v0.1
//install clear cache ...
npm install
```