# Issue in automatic executing post-commit in git hook to sync local and remote directory

Tags: git, hook

I have a server that has bare git repository, and I'd like to use hook to sync the contents with a working so that I can sync my local directory to the working directory in the server.

Googling here and there; this is what I have done so far.

#### ssh setup

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/13542644/260127 and [Dummy questions about setting up git on amazon cloud ec2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18439760/dummy-questions-about-setting-up-git-on-amazon-cloud-ec2)

local: `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 1024` and name it `id_rsa_aws`. Then `id_rsa_asw` and `id_rsa_aws.pub` file is created.

access to the server: `ssh -i amazon-generated-key.pem ubuntu@example.com`

append the generated `id_rsa_aws.pub` key into `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

#### creating a git bare repository

server: `mkdir -p ~/git/dumb.git; cd ~/git/dumb.git; git init --bare`

local: `git clone ubuntu@example.com:git/dumb.git`

- [What does git "updating currently checked out branch" warning mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738154/what-does-git-updating-currently-checked-out-branch-warning-mean)

#### Push from server's working directory

server: `git clone ~/git/dumb.git`

#### Push from local working directory.

Make some changes in a local directory.

- local: `git add .; git commit -m "...";`
- local: `git push --set-upstream origin master`

  - This is the one time execution, then I can use `git push`
  - [Why can't I push to this bare repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157730/why-cant-i-push-to-this-bare-repository)

#### Create a hook

Make a `~/git/dumb.git/hooks/post-commit`, then make it runnable with `chmod a+x post-commit`.

```
#!/bin/bash

unset GIT_INDEX_FILE
git --work-tree=/home/ubuntu/dumb --git-dir=/home/ubuntu/git/dumb.git checkout -f
```

#### ISSUE

When I push from my local machine to server, there is no issue.

```
dumb> git push
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 278 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ubuntu@prosseek.com:git/dumb.git
   5964789..b29c160  master -> master
```

However, the post-commit is not invoked automatically. I can login to the server, and execute the `post-commit` and the working directory is synced.

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hook was wrong, the hook script should have been `post-receive` not `post-commit`. Hints from 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-git-hooks-to-automate-development-and-deployment-tasks

This is the content of the `post-receive` hook.

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                               

unset GIT_INDEX_FILE                                                                                      

while read oldrev newrev ref                                                                              
do                                                                                                        
    if [[ $ref =~ .*/master$ ]];                                                                          
    then                                                                                                  
      echo "Master ref received.  Deploying master branch to production..."                               
      git --work-tree=/home/ubuntu/dumb --git-dir=/home/ubuntu/git/dumb.git checkout -f master            
      echo "Ref $ref successfully received.  Doing nothing: only the master branch may be deployed on this server."                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    fi                                                                                                    
done
```

Comment: There is another issue with this approach, I posted another question for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33812206/how-to-sync-the-stageindex-and-working-directory-after-git-hook-post-receive